# URL manager in Yii flow

Tags: php, yii

i have implemented project in Yii. i have issue with URL manager configuration. I done URL management successfully but when i rendering the one i want to be display only name ie

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
                            'Home'=>'site/index',
            //'cuisine'=>'recipe/index3',

            'cuisine/<:\w+>/<id:\d+>/' => 'recipe/index3',
                            //'<id:\w+>/'=>'recipe/index3',
                            '<title:.*?>/p/<id:\d+>'=>'product/view',
            'holidays/<name:\w+>/<id:\d+>/'=>'recipe/index1',
            'calories/<name:\w+>/<id:\d+>/'=>'recipe/index2',
```

above code is working fine. but recipe/index3 instead of cuisine. i want to be show. i given above statement then i commented because its not working so that. 
the next statement is working fine. but when render the page like wise displaying

```
http://kitchenking.ebhasin.com/recipe/index3/name/German
```

in above link. wants to be show like this.

```
http://kitchenking.ebhasin.com/cuisine/German
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
'cuisine/<name:\w+>/<id:\d+>/' => 'recipe/index3',
```

Comment: I mean, have u used 'name' before colon, the way I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: sorry the links like http://kitchenking.ebhasin.com/recipe/index3/name/American. same only showing

Answer (score 1):

Remove the ID from your rule:

```
'cuisine/<name:\w+>' => 'recipe/index3',
```

The proper way to allow titles with multiple spaces, is to have another field called "slug", where you copy the title and convert all whitespaces into dashes before you save. Use the slug for URLs instead of title. There is no simpler solution for this.

Put this in your model:

```
protected function beforeSave() {
    $this->slug = preg_replace('/[^a-z A-Z]+/', '-', $this->title);
    return parent::beforeSave();
}
```

Then use this for URLs:

```
<a href="/cuisine/<?= $model->slug ?>"><?= $model->title ?></a>
```

Comment: this comment is working earlier but. if table data two words ie(holiday recipes) if one word without white space ie(holiday). above code is working. please tell how to over come these issue

Comment: pl suggest me one sample coding